# scrolling tabwidget

Tags: android

how can i scroll the tab widget in an android application. i tried to apply horizontal scroll view for the tab host,but in that whole screen is scrolling horizontally.i need the the rectangle tab widget to scroll alone horizontally while keeping the screen static.how can i do this any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that I understand you correctly and that you only want to scroll the tabs rather than the content, wrap just the `TabWidget` in a `HorizontalScrollView`, rather than the entire `TabHost`.