# TabWidget tab limit

Tags: android, tabcontrol

I have an android application that currently has 9 tabs. Whenever a new tab is added, the widths of all the tabs are adjusted smaller. I feel that adding another tab will make the tabs too small. Is there a way to have a right/left arrow appear on the side of the TabWidget, similar to .NET tab controls, or would it be better to wrap a TabWidget in a HorizontalScrollView as described here? [scrolling tabwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495618/scrolling-tabwidget)

Comment: Just a note, remember not every device has the same physical width, so 9 tabs might be reasonable on one device, might be horrible on another, and might be amazing on a tablet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your `TabWidget` into a `HorizontalScrollView`, so you could scroll the tabs.

For an example, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799320/android-remove-space-between-tabs-in-tabwidget/5804436#5804436).

If you need buttons on the two side of your tabs, you can wrap further the layout: 
put the `HorizontalScrollView` inside a `RelativeLayout`, and place `Buttons` to the left and right side of it. In the buttons' `OnClickListener` you can scroll the `TabWidget` programatically.

Comment: According to this, putting a TabWidget in a ScrolLView does nothing. http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/

Comment: Please read carefully the article you've shared, that explains how to proceed. It says it's not enough to put the `TabWidget` into a `ScrollView`, you have to set some attributes as well (as the post i've shared clears it too).

Comment: Yes, it says to use a HorizontalScrollView, not a ScrollView. Edit : Oh, you said "horizontal ScrollView", and you mean HorizontalScrollView.

Answer (score 6):

Simply putting `TabWidget` in a `HorizontalScrollView` will meet a problem:
`View` in `TabWidget` will not fill the screen and have different width.
You can avoid it by setting its minWidth and set the `HorizontalScrollView`'s android:fillViewport as true.

```
<HorizontalScrollView ... android:fillViewport="true">  
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" ... />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and

```
int dips = 70; // The min width you want in DIP
int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) dips, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    TabWidget widget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View v = widget.getChildAt(i);
        v.setMinimumWidth(pixels);
    }
}
```

So you don't need to make your own `View` for `TabSpec` indicators.

Comment: +1 ! Your solution saved  me 30mins of running around between links asking to just add HorizontalScrollView and android:fillViewport="true" ! Thank you!

Comment: A great answer to a question I couldn't find elsewhere.